# PHP Fuzzy Search and replace in strings?

Tags: php, fuzzy-search

I would like to know if it's possible to have a fuzzy search coupled with a str_replace.

To be more clear, here's an example:

```
$data = array('my first word', 'myl second word', 'my third words')
```

I would like to find a way to replace every occurence of 'my word', with a fuzzy search for typos and plural.

End results would looks like something like this:

```
$data = array('first', 'second', 'third')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundaries in a regex with `preg_match` to accomplish this. Assuming you already know the terms you want to find...

```
$goodterms = array('first', 'second', 'third');
$datas = array('my first word', 'myl second word', 'my third words');
foreach($datas as $data){
    if(preg_match('/\b(' . implode('|', $goodterms) . ')\b/', $data, $matches)) {
        $match[] = $matches[1];
    }
}
print_r($match);
```

https://3v4l.org/H0Y8k

The `|` is an alteration. The `()` makes a group. The `\b`s makes sure whatever was matched in the group doesn't have leading/trailing content. https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: Thank you, but I actually do not know the terms I'm looking for, I only know the terms I don't want.

Comment: @Tayax What are the terms you dont want?

Comment: "my word" with a fuzzy search